# Which server is used to run a Flask app in PyCharm?

Tags: python, flask, server, centos, pycharm

I have a web app with Flask, and I am working on PyCharm. While creating this app I didn't have to set up any server to run it on, so my question is which server is this app using? Does PyCharm have its own server already configured?

I'm working on Centos 7.

Comment: Flask comes with its own development server, and can run on various servers in production: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/deploying/

Comment: thank you for you answer